# Bordered anchor text -> exclude images

Tags: css

I want to apply a `border-bottom: solid 2px` to anchors (because it looks much better than `text-decoration: underline` but I want to exclude images within that anchor from getting a border-bottom.

```
<a>I have a border</a>

<a>I have a border too <img src="img.jpg" title="I have no border" /></a>
```

My guess was

```
a > * {
    border-bottom: solid 2px;
}

a > img {
     border-bottom: none;
}
```

But that won't work because `> *` is expecting an element within the anchor, it doesn't apply to raw text.

Comment: You're right. You'll need to either wrap the text in a `span`, or wrap the `img` in a different `a.no-border` element.

Comment: That's a problem unfortunately, the html is CMS generated and it doesn't put anchor text in an element (like `span`)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a clean answer to that without using a `span` :

HTML

```
<a>No border<img alt="No border"/><span>Border</span></a>
```

CSS

```
a > span {
    border-bottom: solid 2px;
}
```